# Can I Simplify my Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

I have built a Google Sheet using scrips to automatically timestamp certain events on the sheet upon edit.

Two of the timers are built to time just the first edit of two particular cells:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "SUBARU" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 19);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Two additional timers time any instance two other cells are edited:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "SUBARU" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) { 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 15);
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

And three other timers time when three specific entries happen in one particular cell:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "SUBARU" ) { 
 var r = s.getActiveCell();

 if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) {  
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 20);
  if( r.getValue() === "3 - Menu Ready")
    nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  }
  }
  }
```

My problem is that I have seven scripts per sheet, and 4 sheets using the scripts (so 28 total scripts running). My Google quote is 30 scripts running at the same time. Can anyone think of ways I can simplify these scripts to run quicker or combine any so that I have fewer running at any given time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for this is to group all logic into one "onEdit" function.

Here's my code approach/suggestion to handle it:

```
if(s.getName() == "SUBARU") {
  //put the logic to handle sheet SUBARU
} else if(s.getName() == "ABC") {
  //put the logic to handle sheet ABC
} else if(s.getName() == "DEF") {
  //put the logic to handle sheet DEF
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked and helped you, @AnthonyIanucilli!